# vim netrw doesn't work

Tags: ubuntu, vim

I've installed Vim  7.4 and Netrw plugin v149 over Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

When I try to open a directory with command `$vi /your/path/` it returns an error message: `"/your/path/  is a directory"` but in my older versions it opens the directory with netrw and works fine.

But when I run `$vi .` from command line it runs without problem.

What would be the problem?

Comment: Are you sure that `vi` is `vim`? Vi might actually be vi. Do you have a vimrc? If you don't it probably won't work since plugins aren't loaded. (You need to be in nocompatible mode I think)

Comment: it happens with vim and vi commands... when I run `vim .` it shows without problem.

Answer (score 1):

The "error message" about ... is a directory is what vim normally produces when asked to edit a directory.  This message appears even when netrw is active.  A possible reason for your plight is that vi is a "tiny"  build that comes with your o/s -- see if   "where vim"  differs from  "where vi".  Netrw is not supported by tiny builds of vim.  Also try  "vim --version"  and "vi --version" to see what's supported by your vim/vi.  Netrw needs +eval (which a tiny build does not support).

Answer (score 0):

This is a strange problem. Try updating to the [latests version, 1.53r](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#NETRW).

If it doesn't solves the issue, try to debug it yourself. Check `:help netrw-debug` for detailed instructions about enabling debug messages.

Comment: I installed the last version and the command `vim .` is not working.

Comment: @IvanCachicatari What about activating the debug messages?

Comment: I'm trying to enable debug and I will post the logs